# Work Done By Applied Force In Inclined Plane Problem (Without Friction and Without Changing Kinetic Energy)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

[image]

I know that the work done by gravity in going from A to C, and from A to B to C is the same. I also know that the work done by an applied force in going from A to C is the same as negative of the work done by gravity if there is no change in kinetic energy. But what is the work done by an applied force in going from A to B to C if there is no change in kinetic energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will still be the negative of the work done by gravity.

By the work-energy theorem, the work done by all forces acting on the body is equal to the change in kinetic energy.

$W_{net}=\Delta K$ 
$W_{gravity} + W_{force} + W_{normal} = 0 $ (there is no change in KE) 
$W_{normal} = 0$ as the normal force does no work (it is perpendicular to the direction of motion). 

Therefore, 
$W_{force} = -W_{gravity} = - (-mgh) = mgh.$

**Explanation** 
It is given that the kinetic energy doesn't change, so the body must be moved very slowly. Since there is no opposing force in the horizontal direction, a *very small*  force would be sufficient to move the body from $A$ to $B$. Thus, the work done by this force in going from $A$ to $B$ would be zero. 
After this, the body is moved from $B$ to $C$ against gravity, so the work is done against it.